# How to prevent Magit from asking where to push a branch?

Tags: magit

When calling `magit-push-current` with `P P` from the status buffer, `Magit 2.1.0` asks me where to push the branch on the first time, when upstream is not set.

How can it let automatically generate the name as it used to do before?

Comment: In case you don't know, the auto-generated name is one of the completion options. So, the first time you push `some-branch-name` to the `origin` remote, you can probably just type `o TAB s TAB` and you'll get the name you want.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know, thank you. The problem is that I have a lot of branches starting with the same prefixes, which is not very handy, also I always put on remote branches with the same name as the local branches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update: The "push branch" mentioned below has been implemented by now.See the [documentation about branching](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Branching.html) for more information.*

You have to set the upstream branch once. Once you have done that <kbd>P P</kbd> pushes to that *and* you will get lists of unpulled and unpushed changes in the status buffer (provided there are any).

There are various ways to set the upstream branch. You could use the `--set-upstream` switch from the push popup: <kbd>P -u P</kbd>. Or use the command which sets the upstream and does nothing else: <kbd>b u</kbd>.

Also Magit now automatically sets the upstream branch when creating a new branch, provided the "starting point" is a branch name. This works for local and remote "upstreams". But note that if you pick a local branch as the starting point, then that won't help you with pushing. Pushing from the current repository to the current repository obviously doesn't make sense, and is disallowed.

So when the "upstream" branch is in fact another local branch, then <kbd>P P</kbd> behaves as if no upstream branch were configured, and behaves exactly like <kbd>P e</kbd>. The same is the case if no upstream is configured at all.

This due to a limitation in Git: one can only associate *one* other branch with some branch, and that branch is then called the "upstream branch". It would be better if there were at least an "upstream" and a "publish" branch. I intend to implement that in Magit eventually. See issue [#1485](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1485).

So if you want to be able to push with just <kbd>P P</kbd> then the "upstream" branch has to be e.g. "origin/master", not "master".

---

I am considering adding a push variant which always runs just `git push` without any arguments. What that does would then depend exclusively on Git configuration.

Comment: I branched from `master` and it didn't set upstream, should I maybe branch from `origin/master` to have the upstream automatically set?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Branching from `origin/master` set `origin/master` as upstream, but I would have expected to have `origin/branch-name` as upstream.

Comment: If that's what you want then it is best to do it during push. `P -p P <... completion ...> RET` Note that `origin/branch-name` is offered as a completion candidate, so you don't have to type it out.

Comment: This is painful when you're using gitflow and pull requests for code review, with a branch per feature, because you typically only ever push once, and it's always to create a remote branch with the same name as the local branch. Pushing to a different named branch would be an end run around code review.

Comment: @BarryKelly This answer is outdated. What you want is `P p`.

Comment: I can't really understand this answer, but in the current version of Magit, the following works for me: `P p <TAB> <RET>`. The `<TAB>` command autocompletes `origin` and there is no need to fill in the rest of the branch name, it works it out.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following advice which automatically enables `--set-upstream` when the current branch doesn't have an upstream yet:

```el
(defun magit-push-arguments-maybe-upstream (magit-push-popup-fun &rest args)
  "Enable --set-upstream switch if there isn't a current upstream."
  (let ((magit-push-arguments
         (if (magit-get-remote) magit-push-arguments
           (cons "--set-upstream" magit-push-arguments))))
    (apply magit-push-popup-fun args)))
(advice-add 'magit-push-popup :around #'magit-push-arguments-maybe-upstream)
```

Combined with ido completion this allows pushing a new branch with <kbd>P P RET</kbd>:

```el
;; NOTE: requires ido-completing-read+
(setq magit-completing-read-function #'magit-ido-completing-read)
```

Comment: This is so cool! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just create the new branch with `b c` and then edit the `.git/config` file to point to `origin/branch` rather than monkeying around with all the magit 2 stuff, which doesn't seem to work anyway.

Change:

```
[branch "fix_something"]
  remote = .
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

To

```
[branch "fix_something"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/fix_something
```

This works, whereas I still haven't found a key combination in magit2 that accomplishes the same thing.  Trying to set the remote doesn't work because it doesn't exist on origin yet.

Comment: The upstream can be set using `bu`. But that uses `git branch --set-upstream-to` and as you know Git cannot set a non-existent branch as the upstream and so Magit cannot either.

Comment: @tarsius magit 1 seemed to do what I needed it to. I'm just trying to get back some semblance of that workflow.